# Compare 2 values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label, valueerror

Hi I have this dataframe

[image]

and I am trying to compare which candy among `'Almond Joy'` and `'3 Musketeers'` has the highest `winpercent`(last column).

```
musketeers = candy_data.loc[candy_data.competitorname == '3 Musketeers']['winpercent']
almond = candy_data.loc[candy_data.competitorname == 'Almond Joy']['winpercent']

print(musketeers)
print("===========================")
print(almond)

if musketeers > almond:
    more_popular = musketeers
else:
    more_popular = almond
```

But I got this error. Can someone tell me what is the problem here?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get scalars, not series.

Try:

```
musketeers = candy_data.loc[candy_data.competitorname == '3 Musketeers']['winpercent'].mean()
almond = candy_data.loc[candy_data.competitorname == 'Almond Joy']['winpercent'].mean()
```

Comment: `musketeers = candy_data.loc[candy_data.competitorname == '3 Musketeers']['winpercent'].values[0]`

`almond = candy_data.loc[candy_data.competitorname == 'Almond Joy']['winpercent'].values[0]`

This one also worked

Comment: Yes. I put `mean` in case you might have several values. For a single item it doesn't make a difference ;)